# Create 1 bit bitmap (monochrome) in php

Tags: php, bitmap, bit

I'm looking for the possibility of write a 1 bit bitmap from a string with this content:

```
$str = "001011000111110000";
```

Zero is white and One is black.
The BMP file will be 18 x 1 px.

I don't want a 24bit BMP, but a real 1bit BMP.

Does anyone know the header and the conversion method in PHP?

Answer (score 5):

That's a little bit of a strange request :)

So, what you'd want to use here is php-gd, for a start. Generally this is included when installing php on any OS with decent repo's, but just incase it isn't for you, you can get the installation instructions here;

http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.setup.php

First, we'll need to figure out exactly how big the image will need to be in width; height will obviously always be one.

So;

```
$str = $_GET['str'];
$img_width = strlen($str);
```

strlen will tell us how many characters are in the $str string, and since we're giving one pixel per character, the amount of characters will give us the required width.

For ease of access, split the string into an array - with each element for each separate pixel.

```
$color_array = str_split($str);
```

Now, let's set up a "pointer", for which pixel we're drawing to. It's php so you don't NEED to initalise this, but it's nice to be tidy.

```
$current_px = (int) 0;
```

And now you can initialise GD and start making the image;

```
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($img_width, 1);
// Initialise colours;
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
// Now, start running through the array
foreach ($color_array as $y)
{
  if ($y == 1)
  {
    imagesetpixel ( $im, $current_px , 1 , $black );
  }
  $current_px++; // Don't need to "draw" a white pixel for 0. Just draw nothing and add to the counter.
}
```

This will draw your image, then all you need do is display it;

```
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Note that the $white declaration isn't needed at all - I just left it in to give you an idea of how you declare different colours with gd.

You'll probably need to debug this a bit before using it - it's been a long time since I've used GD. Anyway, hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I'm looking for a bmp generator 1bit monochrome, possibly in pure php. Finally I found the correct way and the solution and now I can generate a correct 1bit bmp monochrome image! With this solution I can generate a barcode raster image with the lowest possible dimension ready for the print ripper.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, I found some classes that can assist you with using GD to create BMP images; you can find these here: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5991-PHP-Load-and-save-images-in-the-BMP-format.html

I hope the rest of the info was at least useful to you :)

Answer (score 2):

That's NOT a strange request.

I completely agree with the purpose of the question, in fact I have to manage some 1bit monochrome images.

The answer is:

- GD is not well documented in PHP website.
- When you want to create an image from scratch you have to use `imagecreate()` or `imagecreatetruecolor()`
- It seems that both of the just mentioned methods (functions) cannot create 1bit images from scratch.
- I solved by creating an external image, 1bit monochrome png, loading it with `imagecreatefrompng()`.

In addition: I've just downloaded the official library open source code from here[Official Bitbucket Repository](https://bitbucket.org/libgd/gd-libgd/downloads)

What I've found in `gd.h`?:

The definition of the upper mentioned functions:

```
/* Functions to manipulate images. */

/* Creates a palette-based image (up to 256 colors). */
BGD_DECLARE(gdImagePtr) gdImageCreate (int sx, int sy);

/* An alternate name for the above (2.0). */
 \#define gdImageCreatePalette gdImageCreate

/* Creates a truecolor image (millions of colors). */
BGD_DECLARE(gdImagePtr) gdImageCreateTrueColor (int sx, int sy);
```

So the "official" solution is: create a 2 colour palette image with `imagecreate()` (that wraps the `gdImageCreate()` GD function).

The "alternative" solution is to create an external image, 1bit monochrome png, and it with `imagecreatefrompng()` as I said above.

Comment: Can you give code example of "I solved by creating an external image, 1bit monochrome png, loading it with imagecreatefrompng()."

Answer (score 1):

For creating a monochromatic bitmap image without gd or imagemagick you can do so with [pack](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) for converting machine byte order to little endian byte order and some functions for handling string, for reference and more details you can check the Wikipedia page [bitmap file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) or this script on [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/QJ3Lu).

For this example I will be using a more complex input, this just for better explain how each line should be aligned when creating a bitmap;

```
<?php
$pixelDataArray = array(
    "11101010111",
    "10101010101",
    "11101110111",
    "10001010100",
    "10001010100",
);
```

First to convert the input into a pixel array or bitmap data, each line on the pixel array should be dword/32bit/4bytes aligned.

```
$pixelWidth = strlen($pixelDataArray[0]);
$pixelHeight = count($pixelDataArray);

$dwordAlignment = 32 - ($pixelWidth % 32);
if ($dwordAlignment == 32) {
    $dwordAlignment = 0;
}
$dwordAlignedLength = $pixelWidth + $dwordAlignment;
```

Now we can proper align the string then convert it to a array of 1 byte integers and after to a binary string.

```
$pixelArray = '';
foreach (array_reverse($pixelDataArray) as $row) {
    $dwordAlignedPixelRow = str_pad($row, $dwordAlignedLength, '0', STR_PAD_RIGHT);
    $integerPixelRow = array_map('bindec', str_split($dwordAlignedPixelRow, 8));
    $pixelArray .= implode('', array_map('chr', $integerPixelRow));
}
$pixelArraySize = \strlen($pixelArray);
```

Then lets build the color table

```
$colorTable = pack(
    'CCCxCCCx',
    //blue, green, red
    255,  255,   255, // 0 color
    0,    0,     0    // 1 color
);
$colorTableSize = \strlen($colorTable);
```

Now the bitmap information header, for better support BITMAPINFOHEADER (40 bytes header) will be used.

```
$dibHeaderSize = 40;
$colorPlanes = 1;
$bitPerPixel = 1;
$compressionMethod = 0; //BI_RGB/NONE
$horizontal_pixel_per_meter = 2835;
$vertical_pixel_per_meter = 2835;
$colorInPalette = 2;
$importantColors = 0;
$dibHeader = \pack('VVVvvVVVVVV', $dibHeaderSize, $pixelWidth, $pixelHeight, $colorPlanes, $bitPerPixel, $compressionMethod, $pixelArraySize, $horizontal_pixel_per_meter, $vertical_pixel_per_meter, $colorInPalette, $importantColors);
```

The last part is the file header

```
$bmpFileHeaderSize = 14;
$pixelArrayOffset = $bmpFileHeaderSize + $dibHeaderSize + $colorTableSize;
$fileSize = $pixelArrayOffset + $pixelArraySize;
$bmpFileHeader = pack('CCVxxxxV', \ord('B'), \ord('M'), $fileSize, $pixelArrayOffset);
```

Now just concatenate all into a single string and it is ready for use.

```
$bmpFile = $bmpFileHeader . $dibHeader . $colorTable . $pixelArray;
$bmpBase64File = base64_encode($bmpFile);
?>
<img src="data:image/bitmap;base64, <?= $bmpBase64File ?>" style="image-rendering: crisp-edges;width: 100px;"/>
```

```html
<img src="data:image/bitmap;base64, Qk1SAAAAAAAAAD4AAAAoAAAACwAAAAUAAAABAAEAAAAAABQAAAATCwAAEwsAAAIAAAAAAAAA////AAAAAACKgAAAioAAAO7gAACqoAAA6uAAAA==" style="image-rendering: crisp-edges;width: 100px;height: ;"/>
```