# How to use PHP GD to create 1 bit bitmaps (black and white only, no gray)

Tags: php, image-processing, bitmap, image-manipulation, php-gd

**My goal**

I have an existing PNG. It currently has anti-aliasing, or in other words, shades of gray. I want the image to be 1 bit, or in other words, only using the colors black and white. My aim is to do this with PHP GD. I have to do this with an existing image, and can not create the image from scratch using imagecreatetruecolor.

**What I'm trying**

The function I've found that seems best for the job is imagetruecolortopalette
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagetruecolortopalette.php

Here is a simple version of what I'm trying to do

```
$user_design = base64_decode($_POST['input']);
$design_file = fopen('path/filename.png', 'w') or die("Unable to open file!");
imagetruecolortopalette($design_file, false, 1);
fwrite($design_file, $user_design);
fclose($design_file);
```

With this being the key line. The 1 being the "maximum number of colors that should be retained in the palette."

```
imagetruecolortopalette($design_file, false, 1);
```

**Behavior I'm getting**

The image appears unchanged. I'm not sure if I'm using PHP GD correctly, or if this function doesn't do what I think it does.

**Other ideas**

These also seem promising.

imagecolordeallocate seems like I may be able to use it to deallocate colors, but not sure how to do this without calling it 254 times.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolordeallocate.php

imagecolorset seems like I may be able to use it to set the palette, but I'm not sure how to do this for existing images.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorset.php

Mostly I suspect imagetruecolortopallette is the best bet, but any and all ideas welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create 1 bit bitmap (monochrome) in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167706/create-1-bit-bitmap-monochrome-in-php)

Comment: No, because that is how to create a 1 bit bitmap from scratch, and I need to do this with an existing image. I will change my question to clarify this.

Comment: For a 1-bit image, the max. number of colors should be 2. A 1-color image is a flat block of color.

Comment: I didn't get a flat block of color, I got the original image, so either I'm not using GD correctly, or this isn't the correct function. I'm not sure which. I think I'm not able to use a resource like a file with GD, and GD only accepts strings and can only create images from scratch. Any knowledge on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$im = imagecreatefromstring($user_design);
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, -1000);
imagepng($im, 'path/filename.png');
imagedestroy($im);
```

[How do you convert an image to black and white in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254388/how-do-you-convert-an-image-to-black-and-white-in-php)

Comment: This works, however, as per the comments in the question you linked, I had to change it to `imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, -1000);` with `-1000` instead of `-100`

Comment: Also, it is making the background, (or perhaps text on a path elements) black, even when I comment out `IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE` and `IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST`. This, however, is a separate issue and your answer accomplished what I asked for.