# How to convert a "true-color" image to a "black-and-white" image, with PHP?

Tags: php, image, colors, gd

First, I have an original image, which is a *true-color* image. It is saved in [JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) format:

[image: *#1*. The original image.]

This original picture is saved in: *24 bit* image.

---

Then, I could convert it into a *gray-scale* image, after running this simple script:

```
<?php 

$source_file = "1.JPG";

$im = ImageCreateFromJpeg($source_file); 

$imgw = imagesx($im);
$imgh = imagesy($im);

for ($i=0; $i<$imgw; $i++)
{
        for ($j=0; $j<$imgh; $j++)
        {

                // Get the RGB value for current pixel

                $rgb = ImageColorAt($im, $i, $j); 

                // Extract each value for: R, G, B

                $rr = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
                $gg = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
                $bb = $rgb & 0xFF;

                // Get the value from the RGB value

                $g = round(($rr + $gg + $bb) / 3);

                // Gray-scale values have: R=G=B=G

                $val = imagecolorallocate($im, $g, $g, $g);

                // Set the gray value

                imagesetpixel ($im, $i, $j, $val);
        }
}

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($im);

?>
```

And, below is result:

[image: *#2*. The gray-scale image.]

This gray-scale picture is saved in: *8 bit* image.

---

Now, I want to convert it into a **real** *black-and-white* image:

[image: *#3*. The black-and-white image.]

This black-and-white picture is saved in: *1 bit* image.

---

Can you show me: *How to convert a true-color image to a black-and-white image, with PHP*?

Comment: Did you read this question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/31342505/3885509

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you convert an image to black and white in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254388/how-do-you-convert-an-image-to-black-and-white-in-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

friend round the grayscale color to either black or white in your code.
(change or vary if($g> 0x7F) on your requirement)

```
 $g = (r + g + b) / 3
    if($g> 0x7F) //you can also use 0x3F 0x4F 0x5F 0x6F its on you 
   $g=0xFF;
   else
   $g=0x00;
```

your full code should be like :

```
<?php 

$source_file = "1.JPG";

$im = ImageCreateFromJpeg($source_file); 

$imgw = imagesx($im);
$imgh = imagesy($im);

for ($i=0; $i<$imgw; $i++)
{
        for ($j=0; $j<$imgh; $j++)
        {

                // Get the RGB value for current pixel

                $rgb = ImageColorAt($im, $i, $j); 

                // Extract each value for: R, G, B

                $rr = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
                $gg = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
                $bb = $rgb & 0xFF;

                // Get the value from the RGB value

                $g = round(($rr + $gg + $bb) / 3);

                // Gray-scale values have: R=G=B=G

                 //$g = (r + g + b) / 3
    if($g> 0x7F) //you can also use 0x3F 0x4F 0x5F 0x6F its on you 
   $g=0xFF;
   else
   $g=0x00;



                $val = imagecolorallocate($im, $g, $g, $g);

                // Set the gray value

                imagesetpixel ($im, $i, $j, $val);
        }
}

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($im);

?>
```

your can also use following alternative code logic

```
<?php 

header("content-type: image/jpeg");
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg('1.jpg');
imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE); //first, convert to grayscale
imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, -255); //then, apply a full contrast
imagejpeg($img);

?>
```